# Создание миниатюры MSWord, MSExcel

Tags: java, excel, ms-word, thumbnails

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли бесплатные инструменты для создания миниатюрных картинок содержимого документа Excel и Word? Если готовых инструментов нет, то посоветуйте в каком направлении смотреть?

Я пока смотрю в направлении конвертирования документов указанного типа в pdf-документы, а затем с помощью pdf-renderer'а в картинку. Думаю, это не лучший вариант, но пока других не приходит в голову.

Comment: @metalurgus по-моему ты перегибаешь палку. На мой взгляд, вполне нормальный вопрос. Мне вот тоже в общем то любопытно :)

Comment: Речь идет очевидно, о библиотеке, которая бы позволяла генерировать thumbnail'ы документов - тема на мой взгляд заслуживает того, чтобы ее не минусовать

Comment: @Barmaley, спасибо. Вы правильно поняли меня. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @metalurgus, спасибо за критику. Боюсь, что "принтскрин" - это слишком некрасивое и медлительное решение.

Comment: [Здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844961/create-thumbnail-image-for-pdf-in-java) нашел способ преобразовать первую страницу pdf-документа в изображение.

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрим варианты:

1. Воспользоваться какой-нибудь подозрительной либой, генерирующей thumb-ы для всего подряд, вроде [этой](https://github.com/benjaminpick/java-thumbnailer). Заявлена поддержка MS Office и OpenOffice.
2. Воспользоваться API от Open/Libre Office и сгенерить thumbnail с его помощью.
3. Воспользоваться конвертором Office -> PDF (чем-то вроде [JODConverter](https://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/) ), а потом PDF -> Image (чем-то вроде [Ghost4J](http://www.ghost4j.org/)), и поресайзить картинку как надо.

Comment: Odt сам по себе содержит png с превью внутри.

Comment: @Qwertiy, согласен, но у ТС речь про *"Excel и Word"*.

Comment: Если уж ты предлагаешь такую схему конвертирования, то почему бы просто не воспользоваться odt вместо двух промежуточных шагов?

Comment: @Qwertiy, сконвертить Word в ODT и достать картинку?

Comment: Ага - вроде проще, чем сначала в pdf, а потом в картинку?

Comment: @Qwertiy, можете добавить в качестве своего ответа.

Comment: Мне кажется, что должен быть способ напрямую из docx'а получить...

Comment: К сожалению, 2 и 3 вариант несколько сложны потому, что необходимо дополнительно устанавливать пакет самого офиса, чтобы воспользоваться этими функциями. Со вторым вариантом это очевидно, но если почитать [информацию по JODConverter](https://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/wiki/FAQ) (первый пункт FAQ), то понятно, что по смыслу оба варианта сводятся к одному решению. Первый вариант пока рассматриваю. Спасибо.

Comment: Первый вариант "Requirements OpenOffice 3.x/LibreOffice". Он тоже не подходит. Кстати, использует он тот же JODConverter =)

Comment: Видимо, все пути туда ведут )